# How to relate tables and view them

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite

So I am creating this website using django framework: gegeneo.pythonanywhere.com

I have two tables Patient and Diagnosis:

Patient:

```
class Patient(models.Model):
PatientName = models.CharField(max_length = 120);
PatientBirthDate = models.DateField();
PatientInitialWeight = models.PositiveIntegerField();
PatientBloodGroup = models.CharField(max_length = 4);
Patient_Booking_Date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = False, auto_now_add = True);

def __str__(self):
   return self.PatientName;
```

Diagnosis:

```
class Diagnosis(models.Model):
    PatientVisitDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = False, auto_now_add = True);
    PatientWeight = models.PositiveIntegerField();
    PatientDiagnosis = models.TextField();
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete = models.CASCADE);

def __str__(self):
   return "Diagnosis of: " + self.patient.PatientName;
```

If you take a look at the website at : [Here](http://gegeneo.pythonanywhere.com/patients)

You will see a list of the patients, and when one is clicked it will redirect to his page, I am now facing problems adding Diagnosis view to each patient, I want to make a form with Diagnosis fields and create a view for it, then make the diagnosis of each patient only appear on his HTML page.

So, how can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If I got the idea, you need to get all the diagnosis rows for an specific patient, so you could try this:

```
# Let's say you have a Patient object -> p
p.diagnosis_set.all()  # This will return all the diagnosis for this p Patient.
```